# How do set IMessageFormatter when using the Send method of IBus in NServiceBus?

Tags: .net, msmq, nservicebus

I am currently sending an object to MSMQ via NServiceBus:

```
public void SendMessage(AvailInfo message) 
{
    var Bus = Configure.With()
          .DefaultBuilder()
          .Log4Net()
          .UseTransport<Msmq>()
          .XmlSerializer()
          .UnicastBus()
          .CreateBus()
          .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>().Install()); 

    bus.Send(message);
}
```

Everything was working fine, except that now the consumer of the queue is requesting we explicitly use the ActiveXMessageFormatter.

Question:  How/where would I set this up when sending the message in the snippet above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NServiceBus message formatter is supposed to be used by all the messaging endpoints to communicate with each other. There are four built into NServiceBus: XML (default, not the same as .NET XmlSerializer), JSON, BSON, and Binary.

The ActiveXMessageFormatter is a System.Messaging class and is not related to the formatters above.

It almost sounds like you're trying to use NServiceBus as a client API for MSMQ, and that's not really what it is. You could technically implement your own message formatter for NServiceBus, but I wouldn't recommend it in this scenario.

If this is a one-off situation, I would consider interacting directly with MSMQ via the System.Messaging namespace in this scenario. Using a transactional message would still interact with the ambient transaction present in the message handler.

Comment: I'd also add that you shouldn't be initializing a new instance of the bus every time you send a message.